# Trying to setup google play game services and getting unexpected error

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

I keep trying to setup google play game services and I'm getting an unexpected error.  Anybody know how to deal with this?  I'm blocked by this screen.

[image]

Comment: This is a known issue that is internal to the console - There should be a fix for it soon.

Comment: do they just fix it on their own?

Comment: It is working now.  please comment here if it is not.

Comment: oh sweet!  Thanks Clayton!